# Jtextarea don't show text

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jform

i create in my project a jform on netbeans on Mac , I create him automatically with the drag & drop ,`I put Three button and one jtextarea.
In the main of the project I create a new object of the type of this jform.
the jform appear but the text in the jtextarea don't appear.

netbeans create automatically initcomponent like this :

```
private void initComponents() {

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jButton1.setText("reply");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setText("reply-all");

    jButton3.setText("delete");

    jButton4.setText("forward");

    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 363, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton3)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton4)))
            .addContainerGap(23, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addComponent(jButton4))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 232, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(15, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}
```

i create the constructor like this :

```
public MailRead(Email a){
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        new MailRead().setVisible(true);
    });
    Date d=new Date();
    this.a=a;
    a=new Email("ffd", "edgvxsfz", "h6v4gtrwd","ujyhrstegfw", d,21334231);
    initComponents();

    //System.out.println("-----Email from : "+a.getMittente()+"-----"+"\n"+"-----Object : "+a.getObj()+"-----\n"+a.getEmail());
    String text= "-----Email from : "+a.getMittente()+"-----"+"\n"+"-----Object : "+a.getObj()+"-----\n"+a.getEmail();

    jTextArea1=new JTextArea(text);
}
```

the email code is this :

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

public class Email implements Serializable{
    String mittente;
    String destinatario;
String email;
Date dataInvio;
int id;
String obj;
boolean isnew;

public Email(String mittente, String destinatario,String obj, String email, Date dataInvio,int id) {
    this.mittente = mittente;
    this.destinatario = destinatario;
    this.email = email;
    this.dataInvio = dataInvio;
    this.id=id;
    this.obj=obj;
    isnew=true;
}

public String getMittente() {
    return mittente;
}

public void setMittente(String mittente) {
    this.mittente = mittente;
}

public String getDestinatario() {
    return destinatario;
}

public void setDestinatario(String destinatario) {
    this.destinatario = destinatario;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getObj() {
    return obj;
}

public void setObj(String obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
}

public Date getDataInvio() {
    return dataInvio;
}


public void setDataInvio(Date dataInvio) {
    this.dataInvio = dataInvio;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public boolean isIsnew() {
    return isnew;
}

public void setIsnew(boolean isnew) {
    this.isnew = isnew;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Email{" + "mittente=" + mittente + ", destinatario=" + destinatario + ", email=" + email + ", dataInvio=" + dataInvio + ", id=" + id + '}';
}
```

}
in the contractor I assigned value at the moment in the real code I use the parameters of MailRead
how can solve to read the email in jtextarea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
jTextArea1=new JTextArea(text);
```

Don't create a new JTextArea.

You want to add text to the existing text area that has been added to the frame. So you would use:

```
jTextArea1.append(text);
```

This means when you create your `MailRead` class you need to pass the text area as a parameter to the `MailRead class as well as the Email parameter so your`MailRead` class can append text to the text area.

Comment: ouch , sorry I've tried new ways, initially I used append() after setText() and insert() but there is always the same problem , now just for try I use append like your answer but the result is the same, the jtextarea don't show me the text

Comment: Did you try adding text when you first create the text area to make sure it is added to the frame correctly. If you add the text area to the frame AND you pass the same text area as a parameter AND you use the append(...) method on this variable then it will work.